# Trying to create a boxplot in ggplot 2

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm very new to R please bear with me

I want a super simple line of boxplots with 0,10,20...100 on the X axis and the value for um on the Y axis.  Here is the excel data I have read in.

```
percent | um
0 9
0 9
0 6
0 9
0 6
10 3
10 3
10 3
10 3
10 3
20 9
20 6
20 9
20 9
20 9
30 6
30 6
30 6
30 9
30 9
40 6
40 9
40 6
40 6
40 9
50 3
50 3
50 6
50 6
50 3
60 9
60 6
60 6
60 6
60 9
70 6
70 6
70 6
70 6
70 3
80 3
80 6
80 6
80 3
80 3
90 3
90 3
90 3
90 3
90 6
100 3
100 3
100 6
100 6
100 6
```

I have tried a few different variations of the code , currently it looks like this

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=data$um, x=data$percent)) + geom_boxplot ()
```

and I get the error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55): x, y.
```

I have previously tried to set the percent as a factor, values 0-100 on a 10 increase as it reads 0 but r always tells me that the labels 11 need to be 1 or 55

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df$percent <- as.factor(df$percent)
df$um <- as.numeric(df$um) 

# Then ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x = percent, y = um)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Your boxplot should look very odd since there are not much variety of data present.

[image]

For next time, please post your data in a better format for others can help with solution faster.